# Parallel Vectors factor

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I came across what seems to be a confusing problem to me, I'm studying vector analysis and this problem is not accepting any solution. 
"If A=[1,2,-1] and B=[Bx,By,3], find Bx and By such that A and B are parallel".
My first attempt to solve was doing cross product and set the resultant vector equals zero which yields Bx=5/9 and By = -31/36 but when i want to verify my solution by doing dot product and setting the result equals to 1 it doesn't yield 1.
Is there anything i'm doing wrong here ? Any help and notes will be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you try $B=-3A$? parallel vectors basically means proportional

Comment: The dot product of two parallel vectors is not necessarily 1 (that's only if they're both unit vectors).  Also, I think you did the cross-product calculation incorrectly, and as fonfonx and Dr. Sonnhard Graubner are saying, there's a much easier solution.

Comment: Moreover, since the signs of the known third components of $A$ and $B$ differ, the vectors point in opposite directions, so their dot product will be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write $$\alpha[1;2;-1]=[bx;by;3]$$
from the last equation we get $$\alpha=-3$$ can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To be parallel, we need:

$$\frac{B_x}{1}=\frac{B_y}{2}=\frac{3}{-1}\implies B_x=-3 \quad B_y=-6$$